# Capturing a selected URL on a safari webpage to a textfile using Applescript

Tags: url, applescript, text-files

using SAFARI as a webbrowser, i would like to store a URL I selected with the mouse to a text file. I think thsi could be possible with the context menu (right mouse click) and the "service" functionality.

Could anybody help me ?

I tried to do that with the AUTOMATOR tool without using Applescript. But any combination of the predefined tools didn't work.

Comment: Show your work.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple task. You can use any of the 5 following Javascript commands. Of course, you must first select the link with the right mouse button.

```
tell application "Safari"
    set selectedText to (do JavaScript "''+window.getSelection();" in front document) -- (Two single quotes before the plus sign.)
    -- or:
    set selectedText to (do JavaScript "window.getSelection()+'';" in front document)
    -- or:
    set selectedText to (do JavaScript "\"\"+window.getSelection();" in front document)
    -- or:
    set selectedText to (do JavaScript "window.getSelection()+\"\";" in front document)
    -- or
    set selectedText to do JavaScript "var selObj = window.getSelection();
        var selStr = (selObj).getRangeAt(0);
        unescape(selStr);" in document 1
end tell


write_to_file(selectedText, (path to desktop as text) & "myURL.txt", false)


on write_to_file(|data|, target, append)
    try
        set open_target_file to open for access file target with write permission
        if append is false then set eof of open_target_file to 0
        write |data| to open_target_file starting at eof
        close access open_target_file
        return true
    on error
        try
            close access file target
        end try
        return false
    end try
end write_to_file
```